# Passing a variable in php include

Tags: php

how to pass a variable in php include, i am new in php

This is what I was trying to do

```
include_once 'task_include.php?id=pot';
```

get an error like this
`Warning: include_once(task_include.php?id=pot): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just set variable before including the file, and it will be available in included file. Have you tried it?

Comment: Define variable above include line and then you can access it inside the include file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass variable in the include_once.

Why don't u perform get and post methods.

use form action.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass variable in the include_once.

Answer (score 0):

include loads a local php file an "pastes" the content into the actual scope.... 
it isn't that nice, but for your case you could do this

```
$id="pot";
include_once "task_include.php";
```

inside task_include.php there will be the global variable $id (not $_POST['id'] or something).
it isn't that nice, but i think, it would fit your needs